# Center image with Glide

Tags: android

Im calling the fitcenter method to center an image inside an imgeView.

My imageView is width:350dp and height 315dp. When i put an image close to those dimension the imageView seems good but when i display a smaller image, the ImageView tends to smaller with the image. Documentation says otherwise.Any suggestions?

Calling fitCenter() scales the image so that both dimensions are equal to or less than the requested bounds of the ImageView. The image will be displayed completely, but might not fill the entire ImageView.

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("http")
.fitCenter()
.into(ivImg);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version 4.0.0 Or above Glide, then use the below code.

```
  RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
      .skipMemoryCache(true)
      .centerInside()
      .placeholder(R.drawable.restaurant_icon)
      .transform(new CircleCrop());


     Glide.with(this)
          .load(restaurantsResponse.getRestaurant_cover())
          .thumbnail(0.9f)
          .apply(options)
          .into(toolbarImage);
```

> Kotlin

```
 val options: RequestOptions = RequestOptions()
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .centerInside()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.restaurant_icon)
        .transform(CircleCrop())

    Glide.with(this)
        .load(restaurantsResponse.getRestaurant_cover())
        .thumbnail(0.9f)
        .apply(options)
        .into(toolbarImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `.centerCrop()` should do the trick

Try something like this:

```
GlideApp
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is expected since the image is smaller than ImageView dimension. please refer to documentation at https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Transformations
you can use `centerCrop()` instead if you want your image to scaled & cropped at the center portion of the image

or you can use custom transformation

Comment: But it says "but might not fill the entire ImageView". Its wrong documentation

Comment: @Nick are you sure the imageview is become smaller? may be it because the imageview has no background, so it looks smaller (fit) with the displayed image

Answer (score -3):

Use Picasso library.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Example 
   Picasso.get().load("urlOfTheImage").into(imageView);

[See here for detail desription](http://square.github.io/picasso/)